# Group row by specified value

Tags: sql

I have data like this :

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| German | 4 |
| French | 1 |
| FrenchSecond | 1 |
| English | 2 |

With SQL, I want to merge manually (French and FrenchSecond) and sum the "Value" :

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| German | 4 |
| French | 2 |
| English | 2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a `CASE` expression for this purpose:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN Name LIKE 'French%' THEN 'French' ELSE Name END AS Name,
       SUM(Value) AS Value
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY CASE WHEN Name LIKE 'French%' THEN 'French' ELSE Name END;
```